# Is it safe to use HttpClientFactory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

In my asp.net core MVC application, I'm using `HttpClientFactory` to create `HttpClient` object for requests to API server.

Follows Microsoft document, `HttpClient` object is created new for each time I call `HttpClientFactory.CreateClient()`, so it will be safe for setting values to `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`.

About `HttpMessageHandler` objects, because they are pooled and can be re-used later. So, if they hold cookies information (For example: setting cookies to `HttpClientHandler` object), we will violate thread-safe.

Is my assumption is correct? How could we deal with this problem?

Is it OK if we set cookie in `HttpRequestMessage`, then we will send it with `HttpClient`?

Comment: You should use 1 `HttpClient` instance and use `SendAsync` if you need to manipulate headers and/or cookies and such. Read more [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). Note that the article only highlights the problem, if you need to manipulate the various shared state information in the `HttpClient` you need to use `SendAsync` instead.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, in asp.net core, we should use `HttpClientFactory` to create `HttpClient` object. As you said, we're also able to use singleton for `HttpClient`, but it will cause a problem: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11224. I just wonder if we use `HttpClientFactory`, the pooled `HttpClientHandler` objects can causes problems to thread-safe.

Comment: The `CookieContainer` class itself is thread safe. You can [see the code yourself](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/9a0e15d1777de9c951cec081699be03304b99bda/src/System.Net.Primitives/src/System/Net/CookieContainer.cs#L273) for the cookie container when it manipulates the cookies array.

Comment: @SimplyGed, maybe the CookieContainer is thread-safe itself, but when it is used in case of HttpClientFactory, it can cause the problem. For example:
`1. HttpClient1 send request to API api/checkAccessStatus` => `2. API check if Request1.Cookie contains "HasAccessed" key, if not, set Response.Cookie["HasAccessed"] = true` => `3.  (From other user) HttpClient2 send request to API api/checkAccessStatus` => `4. Since HttpClient2 is created with HttpClientFactory, it can have same HttpHandler (same CookieContainer). API will see that Request.Cookie["HasAccessed"] is true` => Wrong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found the solution to use HttpClientFactory. We should disable `CookieContainer` of primary `HttpMessageHanlder` (it's a `HttpClientHandler`):

```
services.AddHttpClient("configured-inner-handler")
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    return new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        UseCookies = false
    };
});
```