# Is it the HttpClientFactory bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, httpclientfactory

I have an web application and an API application with following code:

Web:

```
public async Task<string> Test()
    {
        var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("test");
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://api.local:5089/api/values");
        var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return str;
     }
```

API:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    { 
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("HasAccessed"))
        {
            return new string[] { "AccessCount", "Greater than 1" };
        }
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("HasAccessed", "true");
        return new string[] { "AccessCount", "First time" };
    }
```

If I call my `Test` action in the first time (on Firefox), the response will be **First time**. But if I call the second time ( in Chrome ), the response will be **Greater than 1**.

This is not correct, because in other browser, it must be considered as the first time.

After investigating (using debug), in the second request to API, I found that pooled `HttpClientHandler` was re-used (as our expectation when we use `HttpClientFactory`) and also the `CookieContainer` of `HttpClientHandler` was also re-used, the **HasAccessed** cookie had value of **true**  => This caused the problem. (I expected this cookie does not exist since it was considered as the first request to API from Chrome)

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: `This is not correct, because in other browser, it must be considered as the first time.` **No**. The Web (`Test` action) is the client calling the API not the browsers

Comment: Where/how does the "Web" part actually run? More preciselly, how is this code related to any browser?

Comment: @Nkosi, you're correct. But in this case, I'd like each request from user to `Test `action will be a new httpClient from `Web` to `API`. If I use `var httpClient = new HttpClient()`, I can achive this purpose, but with HttpClientFactory, I got the problem.
@ZorgoZ, I just update the Web source code, I'd like one request from user to `Web` will have one corresponding new HttpClient from `Web` to `API` and one corresponding cookie from `API`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881531/is-it-safe-to-use-httpclientfactory/53959979#53959979