# Is it possible to configure HttpClient not to save cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, dotnet-httpclient

I have a simple `Asp.Net Core` WebApi where I am using `HttpClient` to send some custom web requests. I am using `HttpClient` like so:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyInterface, MyService>()
...

public class MyService : IMyInterface
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    } 

    public async Task SendWebRequest()
    {
        var url = "https://MyCustomUrl.com/myCustomResource";
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }
}
```

I have noticed that when I send multiple requests, `HttpClient` saves cookies which it received with first **response** in `Set-Cookie` header. It adds those cookies to consecutive **request** headers. (I have inspected this with `fiddler`). Flow:

```
//First requst
GET https://MyCustomUrl.com/myCustomResource HTTP/1.1

//First response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: key=value
...

//Second request
GET https://MyCustomUrl.com/myCustomResource HTTP/1.1
Cookie: key=value

//Second response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

Is there a way to force `HttpClient` not to add cookies?

This happens only in the same session, so if I would dispose `HttpClient` then cookies would not be added. But disposing `HttpClient` might bring some other issues.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See [`HttpClientHandler.UseCookies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.usecookies?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the handler uses the CookieContainer property to store server cookies and uses these cookies when sending requests.

So you'll need to do:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false };
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

If you're using `HttpClientFactory` in asp.net core, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53959979/1086121) suggests that the way to do this is:

```
services.AddHttpClient("configured-inner-handler")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false });
```

Comment: How does this work together with asp.net core DI? I do not want to manually create `HttpClient` instance as this is againts good practice. And if create it manually and can as well dispose it, which will discard all cookies

Comment: @Ramūnas Updated